# OwnerId inconsistency between Case & CaseHistory StandardObject Tables

Tags: case, standard-objects, history-tracking

I have some Cases whose current OwnerId value is inconsistent with the CaseHistory table.

By this I mean, in the CaseHistory Table, the maximum timestamped row with Field = 'Owner' has a 'NewValue' != Case.OwnerId

As a note, I am aware that CaseHistory has the wierd 2 row's per Case.ownerId update, [for ownerId & owner name].
Also I am aware the initial ownerId will not show up in the CaseHistory as a 'NewValue'

This scenario applies to hundreds of different cases.

Are updates to the `Case.OwnerId` field not guaranteed to be tracked in the `CaseHistory` table?

Comment: are those recent cases or historical one 2 years ago?

Comment: recent cases :(